# Linux command to add a word after a specific line

Tags: linux, sed

we need to add the line `<property name="assumeHungTime" value="600000" />`

after the line `<bean id="DataUnpacker" class="com-packer" singleton="false">`

in one xml file . Please let me know the command to add it - using sed?

Thanks,
Ravikanth

Comment: Are you able to paste the file or the surrounding lines in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The follwing `sed` command will do what you want.

```
sed -e '/<bean id="DataUnpacker" class="com-packer" singleton="false">/a<property name="assumeHungTime" value="600000" />'
```

Comment: if you actually want to edit the file, do that command, but add `-i name_of_xml_file` at the end